# Using Vue-router guards with rxjs?

Tags: vue.js, rxjs

I'm want to have some of my routes guarded.

For example like this

```
{
   path: 'guardedPath',
   component: GuardedComponent,
   meta: {requiresAuth: true}
  }
```

And then In beforeEach I'm using method from guard class

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if(!guard.guarded()) {} else {next()}
    }
})
```

I have a class where I'm creatine an Observable from three variables.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/operators/combineLatest';

export class ConfigService {
    constructor() {}

    checkConfig() {
        let storedVar = this.store.state.storedVar;
        let savedVar = this.anotherService.getValue('string1');
        let anotherSavedVar = this.anotherService.getValue('string2');

        return Observable.combineLatest(storedVar, savedVar, anotherSavedVar);
    }
}
```

`storedVar` is `true/false` value from the `store`, `savedVar` and `anotherSavedVar` are `Observables`.

After that In my guard class I'm using this method like so.
I want to map over values from `combineLatest` and based on returned values return `true` or `false` so method in `beforeEach` is called.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export class Guard {
    constructor() {}

    guarded() {
        return this.configService.checkConfig().map((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

**The problem** is that map operator doesn't run. Function itself is working but `data` don't come from `Observable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable` are lazy datastructures. You need to actually subscribe to the `Observable` in order for it to do anything.

Most likely you want something more like this

```
export class Guard {
    constructor() {}

    guarded() {
        return this.configService.checkConfig()
          .map(data => /* Do Some transform logic here */ return data)
    }
}

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        // Subscribe to the result of the guard and process
        // the handler in the callback function.
        guard.guarded().subscribe(guardResult => {
          next(guardResult.allow ? undefined : {name: 'Unauthorized'});  
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Just tried it - still the same. guarded function runs but nothing works inside the map. And subscribe is not triggered.

Comment: I think the problem is in Observable.combineLatest because if I replace if with Observable.create map triggers

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. One of my values in combileLatest wan't an Observable. So I turned it into one and now it works. Although now the problem is that it is still goes to the page with the guard the first time. And if I then toggle back and forth it starts working propertly

Comment: Ok, what fixed it - I moved subscription to beforeEnter from beforeEach and it worked! Thank you for the help.